# Converting sound to keystrokes: can I actually try it out?

Tags: signal-analysis

I heard that there are ways to tell [which keys you press based on your laptop microphone](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~shmat/courses/cs6431/zhuang.pdf). Is there a project that I could run as a proof of concept to actually experience that on my own?

Comment: I made it into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They only conclusive parts of that analysis is that it is possible to recognize typed characters by the same person over time when you have previously run extended machine learning on that person's typing.

This implies that a program must be installed on their computer to really know what they're typing, making this approach totally useless for actual hacking. If a hacker was to implement this, he'd be wasting a lot of time for nothing since the keylogger would already be installed and more precise than anything else.

Comment: I know this is how the study did teach the program what was being typed but if you remove the key logger you now have weekly "encrypted" data. We have lots of methods of description the written word, Yes adding this layer of complexity makes things harder but, by no means makes it impossible.

Answer (score -1):

I understand why they don't want the public to have this code, sniffing passwords across the room is devastating.

So probably not without some serious dedication to data science.

But if you'd want to take a shot, read up on feature extraction and try replicating their diagram. 
Azure ML studio has a free drag-and-drop machine learning editor if i recall.

Comment: Don't know why that was downvoted, i thoroughly searched for some proof-of concept code but couldn't find any. I'm not an expert in the field but i do know you'll have to build it yourself until it gets released. So the answer is probably no, you cannot experience this on your own.